# $\mathfrak{so}(3)=\ker d\phi(I)$ is the Lie algebra of $SO(3)$.

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $\phi: GL(3,\Bbb R)\to S$ defined by $\phi(A)=AA^t$ where $S$ is the subset
of symmetric matrices. I have two questions:

> **Q1:** prove that $\ker d\phi(A)=\{H\in \mathfrak{gl}(3,\Bbb R)|A^{-1}H\in \ker d\phi(I)\}$

I know that $d\phi(A)(H)=AH^t+HA^t$. Thus $\ker d\phi(A)=\{H\in \mathfrak{gl}(3,\Bbb R)|AH^t=-HA^t\}.$

> **Q2:** Prove that $\mathfrak{so}(3)=\ker d\phi(I)=T_ISO(3).$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\phi$ is a quadratic map and $d\phi_A(H)=HA^T+AH^T$. We deduce that
$ker(d\phi_A)=\{H:HA^T+AH^T=0\}$
 $ker(d\phi_I)=\{H:H+H^T=0\}$.

$HA^T+AH^T=0$, is equivalent to $A^{-1}(HA^T+AH^T)(A^{-1})^T=A^{-1}H+(A^{-1}H)^T=0$ and this is equivalent to saying that $A^{-1}H$ is an element of $ker(d\phi_I)$.